# How to use exhaustMap correctly - How to wait for a service call return before sending another request

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I use a button to `initialiseGrid()`. Without disabling the button while the call is ongoing, I'd like to either wait the 1st response returns and then trigger the 2nd request or (even if triggering multiple requests) handle the responses in the exact order the requests took place. I actually tried to use some **rxjs** operators instead of `map`, but I'm quite sure I didn't use them properly.

**Updated on 20/07/2020:**
I guess exhaustMap is the right operator to use. How should I use it inside either `query` or `fetch` method?

Please find my code below:

APs.service.ts

```
public query(token: string, tableName: string, state: any): void {
    console.log("state in query", state);
    this.fetch(token, tableName, state)
        .subscribe((x: any) => {
            console.log("response data", this.data);
            super.next(x);
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.mediatorService.sendMessage("APsRefreshed");
        },
            (err: any) => {
                console.log("err", err);
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        );
}

public fetch(token: string, tableName: string, state: any): Observable<any> {
    let queryStr = `${toODataString(state)}&$count=true`;
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}')/ig, function (x) {
        return x.substring(1, x.length - 1);
    });
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/substringof\((.+),(.*?)\)/, "contains($2,$1)");
    const regex = /T00:00:00\.000Z/gi;
    const noTimeZoneQueryStr = queryStr.replace(regex, '');

    let fetchCallResult = this.http
        .get(`${this.BASE_URL}` + `/` + token + `${tableName}&${noTimeZoneQueryStr}`)
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => ((<any>this.data) = {
                data: response['value'],
                total: /*response['value'].length*/parseInt(response['@odata.count'], 10)
            }
            )),
        //tap(() => this.isLoading = false)
    );
    return fetchCallResult;
}
```

APs.component.ts

```
public initialiseGrid() {
    this.APsService.isLoading = true;
    this.gridViewAPs = this.APsService;
    this.APsService.query(this.token, this.tableName, this.state);
}
```

APs.template.html

```
<kendo-grid #gridView
            [data]="gridViewAPs | async"
            [loading]="APsService.isLoading"
            ...
>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can only see one http call here, where is supposed to be the 2nd call?

Comment: That's right. I mean the 2nd (3rd,4th,etc) call of the same service.

Answer (score 2):

When I need to control the order of execution especially for http calls , I use one of the higher order Map operators

1. concatMap (makes the call in a serial fashion)
2. mergeMap (makes the call in a parallel fashion)
3. switchMap (makes the call, but then if a new request comes in ignores (unsubscribes) the previous call)
4. exhaustMap (makes the call and ignores any new request until the previous call comes back)

An excellent resource for the above can be found here https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

Here is a ***DRAFT*** of your code refactored to call in a serial fashion (i have assumed your button click to be a stream and the map operator to compose your query input). Replace the concatMap with any of the above operators to get the desired order for your http calls.

```
this.btnCLick$ // 1. That's your button click stream
      .pipe(
        map(() => ({token, tableName, state})), // 2. Map all your inputs into one input object from where ever you want
        concatMap(({token, tableName, state}) => { // 3. This operator will wait for the previous call to complete to make the next call (like a Queue)
          let queryStr = `${this.toODataString(state)}&$count=true`;
          queryStr = queryStr
            .replace(/('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}')/ig, 
              function (x) {
                return x.substring(1, x.length - 1);
              }
            );
          queryStr = queryStr.replace(/substringof\((.+),(.*?)\)/, "contains($2,$1)");
          const regex = /T00:00:00\.000Z/gi;
          const noTimeZoneQueryStr = queryStr.replace(regex, '');

          return this.http // 4. This part will make the http calls based on your query
            .get(`${this.BASE_URL}` + `/` + token + `${tableName}&${noTimeZoneQueryStr}`)
            .pipe(
              map((response: any) => ({
                  data: response['value'],
                  total: /*response['value'].length*/parseInt(response['@odata.count'], 10)
                })
              ),
              //tap(() => this.isLoading = false)
            );
        })
      )
      .subscribe(({data, total}) => { // 5. ***When each http call comes back with a response, the subscription will be called
            console.log("response data", data);
            super.next({data, total});
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.mediatorService.sendMessage("APsRefreshed");
        },
            (err: any) => {
                console.log("err", err);
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
      );
```

With is implementation you don't have to worry about disabling your button...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try that. The button is in another component. So, I have no direct access on the button. As shown above initialiseGrid() is called  in ngOnInit() and the grid dataSource is bound to the service. So, I can't use this.btnCLick$.pipe